# Wrong average travel time between stations. Failing test case for Leetcode #1396

Tags: java, arrays, list, linked-list, hashmap

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [1396. Design Underground System](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-underground-system/description/):

> An underground railway system is keeping track of customer travel times between different stations. They are using this data to calculate the average time it takes to travel from one station to another.
>
> Implement the `UndergroundSystem` class:
>
> - `void checkIn(int id, string stationName, int t)`
>
>   - A customer with a card ID equal to `id`, checks in at the station `stationName` at time `t`.
>   - A customer can only be checked into one place at a time.
> - `void checkOut(int id, string stationName, int t)`
>
>   - A customer with a card ID equal to `id`, checks out from the station `stationName` at time `t`.
> - `double getAverageTime(string startStation, string endStation)`
>
>   - Returns the average time it takes to travel from `startStation` to `endStation`.
>   - The average time is computed from all the previous traveling times from `startStation` to `endStation` that happened directly, meaning a check in at `startStation` followed by a check out from `endStation`.
>   - The time it takes to travel from `startStation` to `endStation` may be different from the time it takes to travel from `endStation` to `startStation`.
>   - There will be at least one customer that has traveled from `startStation` to `endStation` before `getAverageTime` is called.
>
> You may assume all calls to the `checkIn` and `checkOut` methods are consistent. If a customer checks in at time `t1` then checks out at time `t2`, then `t1` < `t2`. All events happen in chronological order.

For this leetcode problem, I am passing 52/59 test cases, but I am not able to figure out why I am failing the rest. I cannot compare the output between the expected and what I got because LeetCode truncates the large outputs. Can anyone tell me what the issue here might be?

#### My code

```
class UndergroundSystem {

    HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>> map = new HashMap<>(); //holds player id and station names with t time start
    HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>> cMap = new HashMap<>(); //holds player id and exit station name with t time diff
    public UndergroundSystem() {
        map = new HashMap<>(); 
        cMap = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public void checkIn(int id, String stationName, int t) {
        if(!map.containsKey(id)) {
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(stationName);
        list.add(Double.toString(t));
        map.put(id, list);
        }
    }
    
    public void checkOut(int id, String stationName, int t) {
        //same id then subtract the times
        if(map.containsKey(id)) {
            LinkedList<String> subList = new LinkedList<>();
            subList.add(stationName);
            subList.add(Double.toString(Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(map.get(id).get(1)) - t)));
            cMap.put(id, subList);
        }
    }
    
    public double getAverageTime(String startStation, String endStation) {
        //first map is going to give us the start station
        //second map is going to give us the end station and the time

        // LinkedList<String> l1 = new LinkedList<>(map.values());
        // LinkedList<String> l2 = new LinkedList<>(cMap.values());
        
        double count = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        // HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>> map1 = map;
        // HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>> cMap1 = cMap;

        for(Integer i: map.keySet()) {
            if(map.containsKey(i) && cMap.containsKey(i) && map.get(i).get(0).equals(startStation) && cMap.get(i).get(0).equals(endStation)) {
                sum += Double.parseDouble(cMap.get(i).get(1));
                count++;
           }
        }
        return  count == 0 ? 0 : sum / count;
    }
}

/**
 * Your UndergroundSystem object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * UndergroundSystem obj = new UndergroundSystem();
 * obj.checkIn(id,stationName,t);
 * obj.checkOut(id,stationName,t);
 * double param_3 = obj.getAverageTime(startStation,endStation);
 */
```

Edit:

If anyone is curious how I fixed it, this is what I did, prolly not the best way but still:

```
class UndergroundSystem {

    HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<String>> checkIns = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, int[]> travelTimes = new HashMap<>();

    public UndergroundSystem() {}

    public void checkIn(int id, String stationName, int t) {
        checkIns.put(id, new LinkedList<>(List.of(stationName, Integer.toString(t))));
    }

    public void checkOut(int id, String stationName, int t) {
        if (checkIns.containsKey(id)) {
            LinkedList<String> checkInInfo = checkIns.remove(id);
            String key = checkInInfo.getFirst() + "," + stationName;
            int[] data = travelTimes.getOrDefault(key, new int[]{0, 0});
            data[0] += t - Integer.parseInt(checkInInfo.getLast()); // Calculate travel time correctly
            data[1]++;
            travelTimes.put(key, data);
        }
    }

    public double getAverageTime(String startStation, String endStation) {
        String key = startStation + "," + endStation;
        int[] data = travelTimes.get(key);
        return data != null && data[1] != 0 ? (double) data[0] / data[1] : 0; // Avoid division by zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what is wrong, and what you have tried already? It's much more helpful if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Assuming your average time is what is wrong, it seems like you are not using the start time at all. Are your comments by the map wrong? Should you take the time to travel as endtime - starttime?

Comment: @wolfcastle the start time is in map, and the difference is being put into cMap and I dont know whats wrong, because the same solution works for 52 test cases but fails the last 7. Idk whats wrong, and I havent tried anything else, other than the solution theres here. I am not really sure what else to try. Any pointers would help. This is an easy problem, i just dont know what im missing. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: It helps if those who are interested in helping you with this question have a description of what the code is supposed to do. In the case of LeetCode, you could provide a link: https://leetcode.com/problems/design-underground-system/description/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in your attempt:

- `checkIn` doesn't do anything if the same id was already used for a previous trip (check-in + check-out).
- `checkOut` takes `map.get(id).get(1)` without checking that this was the entry of the *current* trip, which would be the *last* entry in `map.get(id)`. Now you're always taking the same check-in time for *all* the trips that the same person makes.
- Both `checkIn` and `checkOut` create a new list on each call, put the information for one event in it, and then write that list to the relevant map. That means that a map entry will always have a list with the information for exactly one event, never more. There is no code that *extends* a list that was already present in the map.
- `getAverageTime` never looks any further in the linked lists, and just hopes that the station of the first entry will match. This again means that if the same person (`id`) makes multiple trips, you'll not be able to report on all those.

#### Test Case

Here is a simple test case that fails with your code:

In LeetCode format:

```
["UndergroundSystem","checkIn","checkOut","checkIn","checkOut","getAverageTime"]
[[],[1,"A",1],[1,"B",2],[1,"B",3],[1,"C",4],["B","C"]]
```

Or put in code:

```
UndergroundSystem subway = new UndergroundSystem();
subway.checkIn(1, "A", 1);
subway.checkOut(1, "A", 2);
subway.checkIn(1, "B", 3);
subway.checkOut(1, "B", 4);
System.out.println(subway.getAverageTime("B", "C"));
```

#### Suggested approach

I would not continue with this data structure; it is not the best choice: it is not efficient to have to look into the linked lists to find the correct pair of stations to return the average travel time. In fact, if we log the travel information at check-out, we don't need a list of all check-ins that a certain `id` made: they become irrelevant once a trip is completed and we have processed the travel time.

You'll want to structure information in a different way:

- For a given `id` you only need to store the check-in information of the most recent check-in for that card id. There is no need for a linked list. Instead use a pair of station and time.
- For a *pair* of station names you need to keep track of the number of trips and the total accumulated time spent on such trips. This could be a nested map, but since it is given that the station names only have alphanumeric characters, we could use the comma-separated concatenation of two station names (from-to) as the key for a one-dimensional map.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
class UndergroundSystem {
    private class CheckIn {
        String startStation;
        int startTime;

        CheckIn(String stationName, int time) {
            startStation = stationName;
            startTime = time;
        }
    }

    private class Statistic {
        int tripCount = 0;
        int totalTravelTime = 0;

        void logTrip(int travelTime) {
            tripCount++;
            totalTravelTime += travelTime;
        }

        double getAverage() {
            return (double) totalTravelTime / tripCount;
        }
    }

    // Per card id: the most recent check-in information
    HashMap<Integer, CheckIn> checkIns = new HashMap<>();
    // Per pair of stations (concatenated): the overall trip statistics
    HashMap<String, Statistic> trips = new HashMap<>();
    
    public void checkIn(int id, String stationName, int time) {
        checkIns.put(id, new CheckIn(stationName, time));
    }
    
    public void checkOut(int id, String stationName, int time) {
        CheckIn checkIn = checkIns.get(id); // There must be a check-in.
        String tripName = checkIn.startStation + "," + stationName;
        if (!trips.containsKey(tripName)) { // First time someone makes this trip
            trips.put(tripName, new Statistic());
        }
        trips.get(tripName).logTrip(time - checkIn.startTime);
    }
    
    public double getAverageTime(String startStation, String endStation) {
        String tripName = startStation + "," + endStation;
        if (!trips.containsKey(tripName)) return -1; // No such trips
        return trips.get(tripName).getAverage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh gotcha, youre right about the list holding only one previous event for checkin and checkout. I cant believe I missed that. I am, just going to make a custom class and hold info there and go through this problem like that, prolly much easier. I know this structure isnt the best but I was just trying to get it working first and then optimize it. Appreciate the help!